# Why doesn't my grub background show?

Tags: grub2

I've tried to change resolution, colors and background image for my grub menu, but I get no background (well, just a black one, no image).... What am I doing wrong?

This is my `grub.cfg` (omitting the OS's part):

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
set default="${saved_entry}"
if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}

function load_video {
  insmod vbe
  insmod vga
}

insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(hd1,msdos5)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 42509bf9-f3e6-460a-8947-ec0f5c1fbcc8
if loadfont /usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2 ; then
  set gfxmode=1280x1024x24
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(hd1,msdos5)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 42509bf9-f3e6-460a-8947-ec0f5c1fbcc8
set locale_dir=($root)/boot/grub/locale
set lang=es
insmod gettext
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(hd1,msdos5)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 42509bf9-f3e6-460a-8947-ec0f5c1fbcc8
insmod jpeg
if background_image /boot/grub/Serenity_Enchanted_by_sirpecangum.jpg ; then
  set color_normal=black/white
  set color_highlight=brown/light-gray
else
  set menu_color_normal=white/black
  set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
```

The selected image has been copied to `/boot/grub/Serenity_Enchanted_by_sirpecangum.jpg` with no luck.
I'm for sure missing something (probably something obvious) but I don't really get it...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It ended up being the image resolution... I resized it to be exactly 1280x1024 and it worked fine. I guess grub does not know how to resize/scale an image.
Sorry about answering my own question and accepting my own answer... but that's the solution and I think someone could find it useful

Comment: Answering your own question is actually encouraged! See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250208/1333025

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manually editing the config file i would say download Grub Customizer Portable then mark the applications ‘executable’ after download - Right click > Properties > Permissions > Check ‘allow executing as a programme’ then double-click and run
Now Edit -> Prefrences -> Appearance (tab) and edit it.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ty... that's what I used :)... Well actually I installed grub customizer from a PPA... Anyhow... still no luck: my background won't show, even though the config files seem ok.

Comment: are you sure the background was set to transparent?

Comment: Yes, it was.... but isn't that just for the text?

Comment: no the backgorund is placed above the image you set.

Answer (score 1):

Flagging as solved for me since i changed the image format to **.png**. size went up to 400+kb but .jpg was only 190kb. dont know why it supports a larger image. Probably .jpg is unsupported

Comment: You are right, **.jpg** files are only supported with 256 colors or less.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use a lower resolution image too. that worked right away. My screen resolution when booted is 1920 x 1080, but that size would leave the default purple backround up and no image. Using the Grub Customizer GUI (always) I loaded 1280 x 1024 and it loaded, but about 2/3 screen! My 1920 x 1080 is one of the HD sizes, so I looked up the next lowest HD size (1280 x 720) and the GRUB image this size loaded, almost full screen, and all is good. I'm using a HP Pavilion 22xi IPS monitor, and an Asus AMD Motherboard M4A785-M, not sure what exactly the video card is, low powered DVI-D something or other... I guess the boot resolution is lower than the full 1920 x 1080 after booted?

Comment: For my 1920x1080 screen I had to use 1600x900 image file for best results.